# XAML WPF -Why the background image of button does not change?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am new to XAML, and I am trying to change the background image of buttons.
So, the original background image is heart.jpg.
I wrote function changeHearts() that suppose to check if the background image is: skull.png ,
So it will change the image of the button to: heart.jpg .
The problem is that when I call the function, it does not change the image of the buttons.

- Both of the 2 images property is set to: resource.

*Function in my c# code:

```
  private void changeHearts()
  {

    Uri resourceUri = new Uri("/Images/skull.png", UriKind.Relative);
    StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(resourceUri);

    BitmapFrame temp = BitmapFrame.Create(streamInfo.Stream);
    var brush2 = new ImageBrush();
    brush2.ImageSource = temp;



    Uri resourceUri1 = new Uri("/Images/heart.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
    StreamResourceInfo streamInfo1 = Application.GetResourceStream(resourceUri1);

    BitmapFrame temp1 = BitmapFrame.Create(streamInfo1.Stream);
    var brush = new ImageBrush();
    brush.ImageSource = temp1;




    foreach (Button btn in split1.Children)
    {
        if (btn.Background == brush2)
            btn.Background = brush;
        
    }
    foreach (Button btn in split2.Children)
    {
        if (btn.Background == brush2)
            btn.Background = brush;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot compare the 2 ImageBrushes by doing `if (btn.Background == brush2)` operator == of ImageBrush will not compare the 2 images nor their own path. I recommend you to compare something else (bool or something) based on your business logic and on your requirements to choose when to switch Button's Background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that when I call the function, it does not change the image of the buttons. Please help me, any advice will be great.

That is because you compare **references** of `ImageBrush` instances with the `==` operator. The comparison will always fail, because each `ImageBrush` that you define in XAML and in your code is a distict instance with a unique reference. Consequently, they are never equal.

> I wrote function changeHearts() that suppose to check if the background image is: skull.png , So it will change the image of the button to: heart.jpg .

The most simple solution to this is to not compare the image brushes at all. Your buttons either have a *Skull* or a *Hearts* image as background. Now, when you call `changeHearts()` two things can happen:

- A button was *Skull* and will now be changed to *Hearts*
- A button was *Hearts* and will now be changed to *Hearts*

In both cases the result will be that the corresponding buttons will be *Hearts*, so you could just remove the checks and get the same result.

---

Comparing brushes is hard as the `Equals` method won't do the trick either. You would have to create custom comparison logic, e.g. find properties on brushes to compare, but I do **not** recommend it.

An alternative could be to assign the `Tag` of your buttons with an identifier for what is currently displayed, *Hearts* or *Skull*. This could be a custom `enum` or a simple `string`, e.g.:

```
public enum ButtonType
{
   Skull,
   Hearts
}
```

Then assign the the initial button type to your buttons in XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="XLife1" Tag="{x:Static local:ButtonType.Hearts}" Grid.Column="0" Width="80" Height="80">
   <Button.Background>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="/images/heart.jpg"/>
   </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Adpat your methods to check the `Tag` property of button and change the tag if it matches:

```
if (btn.Tag.Equals(ButtonType.Hearts))
{
   btn.Tag = ButtonType.Skull;
   btn.Background = brush;
}
```

Comment: I removed the compare == and it works....  But, I still need help. I want this project to work on every computer, do you know if the UriResourse will work ok?                                          Because, I have tried instead: of /images/skull.png to put the full path of the location of the image and it does not works on other computers, because its the specific location of the image in my computer....

Comment: @Vel Add your images to the project, right-click them and click _Properties_, then set the _Build Action_ to _Resource_. This way the image will be compiled into the library or executable. Then using e.g. `/images/skull.png` as URI source should work, as it references the image built into the executable.

Comment: Ok, I will do it.                                                                                                                               Thank you very much for your help! :)